# How To integrate aadhar e-kyc or aadhar auth using node js

Tags: node.js, aadhaar

I an developing a lawyer and client communication app.. I want to integrate e-kyc or aadhar auth using nodejs...but cant find the resource...I got to know about aadhar card API but know how to use it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.